# Finding an explicit expression for a minimizer

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on the interval (0,1). We consider the energy functional

$F(u) = \int^1_0\frac{1}{2}((u')^2+u^2)\,dx - \int^1_0fu\,dx$

which is well defined for continuously differentiable functions $u$ on $(0,1)$. Suppouse that $u_0$ is a local minimizer of $F$ in the class of $C^1$ functions satisfying $u(0)=a, u(1)=b$ for some fixed $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

This question consists of a few parts but im stuck on one in particular,

Suppose that $a=1,b=e^2,f(x)=-3e^{2x}$. Find an explicit expression for $u_0$.

I have found the Euler-Lagrange equations, $(u_0 -f)-\frac{d}{dx} (u_0'') (u_0') = 0$ but I'm not clear as to how to solve the stated question using this.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Not to be picky, but I think you mean 'minimizer' (and if 'minizer' is actually a term I have not come across, apologies).

Comment: @gnometorule Thats true lol

Comment: I fixed obvious typos, but there may be one in your Euler-Lagrange equation too. Should there be an arithmetical sign between two parentheses?

Comment: @5pm maybe my calculations were in correct, but isnt it just the product of $u_0'$ and $u_0''$?

Comment: That's what I'm saying: your calculations were incorrect. The Euler-Lagrange equation for a quadratic functional is always *linear*, and your equation is not. Once you fix the equation, you'll find it much easier to solve using the standard approach to second-order linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: @5pm im really stumped, isnt $d/du' F(x,u_0,u_0') = u_0'u_0'' = 0 $ since $u_0= 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stated Euler-Lagrange equation is incorrect. (It should have been linear, since the functional is quadratic).
This is the correct derivation of the equations:

1. Write $z=u$ and $p=u'$ in order to abstract away the function $u$.
2. Find $\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$
3. The equation is $-\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=0$.
4. Return to the notation $u,u'$.
5. Take the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$.

In the present case $\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}=p$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=z-f$. 
Therefore, the Euler-Lagrange equation is 
$$-\frac{d}{dx} (u') +(u-f)=0 \tag1$$
which is 
$$-u''+(u-f)=0 \tag2$$
As promised, this is a linear equation, to which standard ODE methods apply.

> That is, the general solution is $u=c_1u_1+c_2u_2+u_p$ where $u_1,u_2$ solve the homogeneous equation (and are found from the characteristic equation), and $u_p$ is a particular solution, found by the method of undetermined coefficients. The last step is to find $c_1,c_2$ that satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: Any chance for assistance here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066495/minimization-of-variational-total-variation-tv-deblurring

Answer (score 1):

The Euler-Lagrange equations are differential equations, since you know all the terms involved in your expression and boundary conditions on $u$ this is a straightforward computation. There are plenty of programs that will solve a diffie for you symbolically or numerically, or if you're feeling perverse you can get a book on ODEs.